# Resolve in router is not updating scope in time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, promise, angularjs-routing

**Hello there,**

I have issue with manipulating with scope variables (with resolve in router) before angular view content is renderer. I am using AngularJS 1.2.16

I have view, where is DIV displayed depending on scope variable.

```
<div ng-hide="data.show">Text to show</div>
```

I have a controller with scope variable `$scope.arived` and im watching this variable, so when it will change, function `toggleText()` in watch callback will set `$scope.data.show` to true/false.

```
app.controller('view1Controller', function($scope, arived) {

   $scope.arived = arived;   // About this im talking about in next paragraph

   $scope.$watch('arived', toggleText);       

   function toggleText(newVal, oldVal) {
     $scope.data.show = !$scope.data.show;
   }

});
```

This is normally working as excepted. The problem comes, when i will use data injection from router trough resolve method.

Lets say i have this router:

```
$routerProvider
  .when('/view1', {
    controller: "view1Controller",
    templateUrl: "/templates/partial1.html",
    resolve: {
      arived: function(dataService) {
         return dataService.check();
      }
    }
  });
```

`dataService.check()` is returning promise and i want to `$scope.arived` in controller `view1Controller` be filled, after promise is resolved.

**This is ALSO working**, but too late. `$scope.arived` is filled, but before Angularjs view is rendered, so text is not visible.

When i try to wrap this setter inside controller:

```
$scope.arived = arived;
```

into `$timeout`, fe. with 1s delay

```
$timeout(function() {
   $scope.arived = arived; 
}, 1000);
```

its working.. but i dont want any not required delay there.

Is there any event, like view rendered or something, where can i fire my setter ?
Or im doing it all wrong ? :)

Thank you

Comment: I also tried wrap setter with event `$viewContentLoaded`, but its not working without success.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should initialize the data.show with value from resolved promise

```
app.controller('view1Controller', function($scope, arived) {

  $scope.arived = arived;   // About this im talking about in next paragraph
  $scope.data.show= arived;   

  $scope.$watch('arived', toggleText);       

  function toggleText(newVal, oldVal) {
    $scope.data.show = !$scope.data.show;
  }

});
```

Comment: I posted much simpler code than i have for better undertand. I need that function, because its doing much more things.  Anyway, i have that varibale set, but too fast before view render.

Comment: Have an example (on plunkr, fiddler) to see? Anyway you could read this article: http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/show-route-only-after-all-promises-are-resolved